# cannot print a defined environment variable inside powershell step in jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having trouble accessing the environment variable that I defined in Jenkinsfile ( Groovy ). 
My situation is that I can access the variable in any step outside the powershell ''' ''' but when I try to access it inside the powershell then it gives null value.

```
pipeline {
     environment {
        APP_BUILD = ''
        BUILD_NUM = ''
        APP_NAME = ''

    }
     agent {
        label 'test'
    }
    stages {
        stage('set env Variables ') {
             steps{
             script {

       APP_BUILD  = "name" 

       echo APP_BUILD
       //prints name which is expected and fine 
       powershell '''
       echo $env:APP_BUILD // does ot print anything
       echo $env:BUILDNUMBER // prints the build number 

       '''
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to search for an solution where they say that if I use powershell """ """ , it might work but then I cannot assign it to other variable as in code below

```
pipeline {
     environment {
        APP_BUILD = ''
        BUILD_NUM = ''
        APP_NAME = ''

    }
     agent {
        label 'test'
    }
    stages {
        stage('set env Variables ') {
             steps{
             script {

       APP_BUILD  = "name" 

       echo APP_BUILD
       //prints name which is expected and fine 
       powershell """
       echo ${env:APP_BUILD} // prints output as expected 
       echo $env:BUILDNUMBER // prints the build number 
$build=${env:APP_BUILD} // gives an error saying groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding 

       """
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

then it echo the output but everytime I try to assign the environment variable to another local variable then it gives error which says 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar situations and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the '$' character when referring to PS variables, otherwise Groovy will try to interpolate:

```
powershell """
   echo "$APP_BUILD"     # it's simpler to let Groovy interpolate
   echo "$BUILDNUMBER"   # it's simpler to let Groovy interpolate
   \$build="$APP_BUILD"  # need to escape '$' when referring to PS variable
   """
```

Comment: THank you @zett42 for the response. Seems like it is working for simple characters but not for variable that outputs special characters. In my situation if the output of $build is just a number for e.g 54 then it is working but if the output of $build is "das_54.zip" then it is erroring out saying that there is no powershell command like that. Just wondering if you could help me here.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by adding "" in the statment like $build = "${env:APP_BUILD}"

Comment: @dasrakhadka The quoting is a good suggestion, I have added it to my answer. Though you can remove the "env:", it doesn't solve any purpose. If you wanted to read a PowerShell environment variable, you'd have to write "\${env:APP_BUILD}".